# In H5PY, what would be the equivalent of datatype H5T_STD_U8LE?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am writing 6 datasets to a new hdf5 with h5py.  3 of them are of one format and 3 of the other.  For 3 of the first set, I use `dt="s103"` which perfectly captures the datatype.  For the other set of 3, I need the datatype to be `H5T_STD_U8LE` to match what another hdf5 file on disc has.  How would I accomplish this when creating a dataset to write out?

Answer (score 0):

In my situation it was `dt='uint8'`.  This would give me the above type